# Adding labels to outliers in a scatterplot

Tags: r, plot

I currently have a matrix (table) like this that contains 6 women's height and weight:

```
V1     V2       V3     V4
1      Bella    161    60
2      Jessica  160    55
3      Indigo   179    72
4      Tina     165    54
5      Sofia    178    70
6      Fiona    163    51
```

On the scatterplot (height vs weight), I want to label the outliers using the female's name. Is there a method to do so? I've tried

```
text(V4, V3, labels=V2)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please do not post an image of data: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: BTW, if that is a frame we're looking at, then ... how are you telling `text` where to find those variables? (Perhaps prepend each variable with `dat$`, or wrap it in `with(dat, text(...))`.)

Comment: Do either answer (or both) answer your question, rrr?

Answer (score 0):

The `text` function doesn't know where to get `V4` and such.

A few options, sticking with base graphics:

1. `text(dat$V4, dat$V3, labels = $V2)`
2. `with(dat, text(V4, V3, labels = V2))`
3. `text(V3 ~ V4, data = dat, labels = V2)`

Demonstration:

```r
plot(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars, pch = 16, col = "gray90")
text(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars[2:4,], labels = cyl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a `ggplot2` approach. Here I include the code using your data but you would have to define what is an outlier. Here the approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(V1=1:6,
                 V2=c('Bella','Jessica','Indigo','Tina','Sofia','Fiona'),
                 V3=c(161,160,179,165,178,163),
                 V4=c(60,55,72,54,70,51),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

We have to define the outlier. Let's say values greater than 175 in `V3` and greater than 69 in `V4` are outliers:

```
#Create label
df$label <- ifelse(df$V3>175 & df$V4>69,df$V2,NA)
```

Now we plot:

```
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=V3,y=V4))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text(aes(label=label),vjust=-0.5)
```

Output:

[image]

Also take note on great suggestions from sage @r2evans. They are very clear!